# How to get Next and Previous values of Enumerator List?

Tags: c#, .net

When am trying to while loop of Enumerator List, How to get Next and previous values. Please find the below code.

```
public static void Main() 
{ 

    List<string> mylist = new List<string>(); 
    mylist.Add("C#"); 
    mylist.Add("Java"); 
    mylist.Add("C"); 
    mylist.Add("C++"); 

    // To get an Enumerator 
    // for the List. 
    List<string>.Enumerator em = mylist.GetEnumerator(); 
    display(em); 
} 

static void display(IEnumerator<string> em) 
{ 
    while (em.MoveNext()) { 
        string val = em.Current; // Want to know Next and Previous values of current value.


        Console.WriteLine(val); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can track the previous item yourself (i.e. store it in temp local variable), but you cannot look at the next item as it will move iterator forward. You can track two previous items yourself and pretend that you are looking on the middle item as the current one (though current actually will be next). Though that is just an exercise for fun, because enumerators supposed to iterate items one by one without look back or forward. You should use `LinkedList` instead

Comment: Thanks John. let me know is there any way to work on it,

Answer (score 6):

Enumerators, in the `GetEnumerator()` sense, are forwards-only, once-only cursors over data. If you want to know the next value: use `MoveNext()` *and look*. If you want to know what the previous value was: you should have remembered it. Since most data structures are *not* doubly-linked lists, and since enumerators are *not even necessarily based on data that is stored anywhere* (you can do some *really* interesting things with iterator blocks), nothing else is possible.

In the specific case of `List<T>`: perhaps use a `for` loop instead of your `foreach`-like enumerator access, and then you can just use `list[i-1]` and `list[i+1]` (after checking your boundary conditions).

---

Note: as a general rule, you should *avoid* using the enumerator APIs directly unless you are *very, very* familiar with what is going on underneath.  Prefer `foreach` or indexer-based access.

---

You could generalize a triplet (previous/current/next) iterator with your own iterator block; the output from `{ 1, 4, 5, 1, 543, 2, 1, 54, 23 }`

is:

```
1-4-5
4-5-1
5-1-543
1-543-2
543-2-1
2-1-54
1-54-23
```

Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<int> { 1, 4, 5, 1, 543, 2, 1, 54, 23 };
        foreach(var t in data.Tripletize())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{t.Previous}-{t.Current}-{t.Next}");
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<Triplet<T>> Tripletize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        using (var iter = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            // read the first triple
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) yield break;
            var x = iter.Current;
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) yield break;
            var y = iter.Current;
            if (!iter.MoveNext()) yield break;
            var z = iter.Current;

            yield return new Triplet<T>(x, y, z);
            while (iter.MoveNext())
            {
                x = y;
                y = z;
                z = iter.Current;
                yield return new Triplet<T>(x, y, z);
            }

        }

    }
    readonly struct Triplet<T>
    {
        public Triplet(T previous, T current, T next)
        {
            Previous = previous;
            Current = current;
            Next = next;
        }

        public T Previous { get; }
        public T Current { get; }
        public T Next { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I did for loop without using the Enumerator list but here I am trying how to use the Enumerator list for next and previous. Please can you suggest me is there any way to work on it.

Comment: @Nama I just explained that this isn't something that you can do with an enumerator, unless you do as Sergey suggested, and buffer *3* items, and treat them as prev/current/next - and then every time you move-next, shuffle everything down by one; frankly, using the indexer is going to be a **lot** easier in the case of lists

Comment: @Nama I've added some code to show how this can be done in the general case - see the edit that shows usage and implementation

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` does not support checking the previous and next items. It provides access only to the current item. If you want to track the previous item you should store it manually in a local variable. Or you should store two previous values and pretend that the current one is the next.

```
static void display(IEnumerator<string> em)
{
    if (!em.MoveNext())
       return;

    string prev = null; // store prev
    string current = null; // store current
    string next = em.Current; // null <- null -> next

    do
    {
        // move 'window' further so that next becomes current            
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = em.MoveNext() ? em.Current : null;
        Console.WriteLine($"[{prev}] <-[{current}]-> [{next}]");
    }
    while (next != null);
}
```

Output with your test data:

```
"[] <-[C#]-> [Java]"
"[C#] <-[Java]-> [C]"
"]Java] <-[C]-> [C++]"
"[C] <-[C++]-> []"
```

---

But there is a data type with required functionality from the box - [doubly linked list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=netcore-3.1)

```
var mylist = new LinkedList<string>(); // instead of List
mylist.AddLast("C#"); 
mylist.AddLast("Java"); 
mylist.AddLast("C"); 
mylist.AddLast("C++"); 
display(mylist );
```

And here you go

```
static void display(LinkedList<string> list) 
{
    var current = list.First;
    while (current != null)
    {

        string val = current.Value;
        // null if there is no next/prev value, but you can just check if node exists
        string prev = current.Previous?.Value;
        string next = current.Next?.Value;

        Console.WriteLine(val);
        current = current.Next;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Something like this :

```
  class Program
    {
        int position = -1;

        public List<string> mylist;

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            position++;
            return (position < mylist.Count);
        }

        public String GetCurrent
        {
            get
            {
                return Current;
            }
        }

        public string GetPrevious
        {
            get
            {
                return Previous;
            }
        }

        public String Previous
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return mylist[position-1];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }


        public String Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return mylist[position];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }


        void Main(string[] args)
        {

            mylist = new List<string>();
            mylist.Add("C#");
            mylist.Add("Java");
            mylist.Add("C");
            mylist.Add("C++");


            display(mylist);
        }

        void display(List<string> em)
        {
            while (MoveNext())
            {
                string val = GetCurrent;
                string val2 = GetPrevious;
                Console.WriteLine(val);
            }
        }
}
```